# Content of div bigger than it should be

Tags: css, html, overflow, whitespace

I am developing a calendar with clickable dates. When a specific date is clicked, a list with times and "Available" or "Unavailable" shows up.

With the timetable I have a small problem.
At the end of my list always stays whitespace that shouldnt be there...

The content is placed in a div with 'overflow: auto'
But when I remove that from my css, then there is no whitespace.

Really weird, can someone plz help me?

JSFiddle: [JSFiddle with problem](http://jsfiddle.net/X554D/)

HTML:

```
<div id="events">
<h2>14 Oktober 2013</h2>
<div class="sub clearfix">
    <p>Uur</p>
    <p>Beschikbaar</p>
</div>
<div id="eventList">
    <div class="event clearfix">
        <p>09:00</p>
        <p>Beschikbaar</p>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="event clearfix">
        <p>12:00</p>
        <p>Beschikbaar</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#eventList
{
    width: 208px;
    border: 1px solid #363636;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 263px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change     `content:".";` to     `content:"";`

So

```
.clearfix:after
{
    content: "";
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/X554D/1/)

Comment: Thanks!! It's fixed :D U will get a usefull vote as soon as I get enough rep :D

Comment: No problem, you can also accept this as the correct answer. That way people know what has fixed the problem.